# Woocommerce - Product Description heading

Tags: plugins, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Currently when I view one of my products and scroll down to read the description
below the tabs and above the text I have input, it has a heading which simply says `description` when I look at the code it is as:

```
<h2>description</h2>
```

nothing complicated lol.

My question though, is how i can customise this heading to suit the products, I cannot find any documentation online other than removing it completely. I dont want to remove it, I want it to be Unique to the product.

For example, maybe adding a bit of code to functions.php that will tailor the heading to the product by using the brand and title for example.

in Yoast there are the options to use:

`%%catogory%%%%sep%%%%title%%`

Most products on my site have multiple categories so I would be looking for something like

`%%brand%%%%sep%%%%title%%` which would give the output - `brand - title`

I dont know if it is possible but any help would be greatly appreciated or even if there might be a suitable plugin.

@Shameem Ali P.K  Provided the code below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading',
'product_description_tab', 10, 1 );

function product_description_tab( $title ) {
global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();

return $categ.'-'. $post->post_title;
}
```

I have found from Yoast what I believe to be the way they call the brand from PWB Plugin as shown below:

```
public function get_product_var_brand() {
    $product = $this->get_product();
    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $brand_taxonomies = array(
        'product_brand',
        'pwb-brand',
    );
    $brand_taxonomies = array_filter( $brand_taxonomies, 'taxonomy_exists' );
    $primary_term = $this->search_primary_term( $brand_taxonomies, $product );
    if ( $primary_term !== '' ) {
        return $primary_term;
    }
    foreach ( $brand_taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );
        if ( is_array( $terms ) ) {
            return $terms[0]->name;
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

I have tried different things but am unsure how to combine the two to give the desired outcome stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the down vote from whoever was nice enough to downvote and run...

I have figured out how to do it... so if anyone else has the same issue, this is what worked for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading','product_description_tab', 10, 1 );

function product_description_tab( $title ) {
global $post, $product;
$brands = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pwb-brand' );
    foreach( $brands as $brand ) 
return $post_excerpt = $brand->name.' - '. $post->post_title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the description tab heading to the product category followed by the name using the following snippet

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading', 'product_description_tab', 10, 1 );

function product_description_tab( $title ) {
global $post, $product;
$categ = $product->get_categories();

return $categ.'-'. $post->post_title;
}
```

According to above code, you can get product brand. I hope that'll solve your issue. let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That code works great, however it returns the category. I have been looking online to find out how to get the brand from the Perfect Woocommerce Brands plugin as opposed to the category. Have you any idea how i might do that or where to find the information

Comment: I have tried replacing the bottom 2 lines with `$brands = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'pwb-brand');

return $brands.' - '. $post->post_title;` but I get array instead of the brand name

Comment: - I have added code above. I was wondering if you or anyone else might know how to combine. I have included the code you have supplied here

Comment: Did issue solve or not?

Comment: The product name is now showing. The code yo provided site the categories, I need the band, so the code did with but it just requires a slight tweak to be what I need

Comment: did you try with this code `get_the_term_list($wp_query->post->ID,'pwb-brand','Brand: ','','','')`  for brand? and if this work then you can combine brand name and product name.

Comment: I did, I put idt where `$categ = is` and it returned `array` rather than the brand name

Comment: I may have entered it incorrectly though

Comment: can you post the whole snippet?